# How to show UNICODE characters stored in MsAccess Database on a browser page?

Tags: ms-access, unicode, asp-classic

I'm using IIS7 on my Windows7 operating system to run my project written in ASP3.0 language with use of Ms Access 2010 database.

Most of the data that I saved on MsAccess DB is in Arabic language. If you have the font you must see example: سلام

Everything was right and I was using my program running on IIS7. But one day, I decided to run this program on another computer too. So, I installed IIS7 and MsAccess2010 on Windows7 on that computer and I ran this program on second computer, I saw that Arabic texts which stored in database are shown like "???????" (Question mark) on browser. But stored data on MsAccess file are not ?????.

I tried to fix this problem by reading different articles, But I cant overcome.
Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

Both the database and your page need to use UTF-8 encoding in order for this to work.

This should be in your `<HEAD>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

If the data was stored as Windows-1251 encoding, as is common when using MS Word Etc., then you're in for a bit of pain. Data will still come out with the wrong encoding.

If this is what you see, you may need to re-load those docs into Word 2007/2010 and re-save them as UTF-8, then re-insert them into the MS Access.

Comment: How can I save data on MsAccess with UTF-8 unicode? I already simply copied and pasted data to MsAccess.

Comment: If it's coming from MS Word, save your doc as UTF-8, then paste it from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, problem still persists.